# Grid afterload or afterrefresh event

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a function that compares cell values in a `grid` and if it finds differences, then it changes background color. But all styles dissapper, when the user reloads the grid. I tried to call this function again on grid store `load` event, but it does nothing, because `refresh` event happens after `load` event and clears styles again. If I instead call this function on `refresh` event, then I get an error. I need something like `afterrefresh` or `afterload` event, but can't find them.

Comment: Did you use the store's or the grid view's `refresh` event?

Comment: Thanks, Mat! I used store refresh event.